# How to save an ImageField class object in a Django session?

Tags: django

### I couldn't save an ImageField class object in a Django session.

The type of object which I like to save in a session is below.

```
<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile'>
```

### The reason I want to do this

is that I want to save the data until the ultimate registration so that this posted image data will not disappear when transitioning from the form to the confirmation page.

I tried below.

#### views.py

```
class ProductRegister(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'app/product_register.html'
    form_class = ProductRegisterForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ctx = {'form': form}

        temporary_product_object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.request.session['product_image'] = temporary_product_object.product_image

        return render(self.request, 'app/product_register_confirm.html', ctx)
```

but error occurred.

#### error message

```
TypeError at /app/product_register/35
Object of type ImageFieldFile is not JSON serializable
```

Here is models.py for reference.

#### models.py

```
product_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thank you 
in advance.

Comment: The error clearly states `ImageFieldFile` can't be serialize, but you can save the `id` of the image, that way you can search it manually in the confirm view.

Comment: Thank you for the very valuable information. Is the id you mention the image itself? Or is it an ImageField class object? It seems that id and pk cannot be found with ImageField class object.

Comment: Sorry, I now see that you're not actually saving the instance in the `form_valid` method, therefore there's no `id` and so my comment is not really useful. May we know how you're saving the instance in the confirm view? That way we can provide you a solution.